# I have build a simple android app. In my activity most of the buttons work but others don't

Tags: android, android-activity

This code which is given below is a java code for one of my activity. I this activity I have used button. Problem is that buttons for condition from A to T works just fine but after them from U to Z doesn't work properly although code is same for all the buttons. needs help.

```
package irtiza.alphabets;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;


public class alphabet_meaning extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //  voices
    String alphabet_meaning_voices = null;
    TextToSpeech tts;
    /////

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet_meaning);


        // Text Voice
        Button voice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_1);
        voice1.setOnClickListener(alphabet_meaning.this);
        //

        // getting values
                Intent intent_get = getIntent();
                Bundle b = intent_get.getExtras();
        ////
        String image_button_values = (String) b.get("ib");

        tts = new TextToSpeech(alphabet_meaning.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }
            }
        });

        ////////// For A
        if ( image_button_values.matches("A") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="A for Apple";
        }
        /// For B
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("B") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="B for Ball";
        }
        /// For C
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("C") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.car);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="C for Car";
        }
        /// For D
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("D") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dolphen);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="D for Dolphen";
        }
        /// For E
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("E") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.elephant);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="E for Elephant";
        }
        /// For F
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("F") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.flower);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="F for Flower";
        }
        /// For G
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("G") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.giraffe);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="G for Giraffe";
        }
        /// For H
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("H") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.house);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="H for House";
        }
        /// For I
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("I") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice_cream);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="I for Ice cream";
        }
        /// For J
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("J") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeep);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="J for Jeep";
        }
        /// For K
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("K") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.kite);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="K for Kite";
        }
        /// For L
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("L") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lion);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="L for Lion";
        }
        /// For Menter code here
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("M") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.moon);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="M for Moon";
        }
        /// For N
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("N") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.net);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="N for net";
        }
        /// For O
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("O") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="O for orange";
        }
        /// For P
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("P") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.parrot);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="P for parrot";
        }
        /// For Q
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("Q") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.quail);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="Q for quail";
        }
        /// For R
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("R") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.rabbit);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="R for rabbit";
        }
        /// For S
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("S") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.shoe);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="S for shoe";
        }
        /// For T
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("T") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tomato);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="T for tomato";
        }
        /// For U
        else  if ( image_button_values.matches("U") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.umbrella);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="U for umbrella";
        }
        /// For V
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("V") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.voilin);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="V for violin";
        }
        /// For W
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("W") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.watch);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="W for watch";
        }
        /// For X
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("X") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.xylophone);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="X for xylophone";
        }
        /// For Y
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("Y") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yak);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="Y for Yak";
        }
        /// For Z
        else if ( image_button_values.matches("Z") ) {
            ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.zebra);
            alphabet_meaning_voices="Z for zebra";
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
//        protected void OnPause () {
//            if ( tts != null) {
//                tts.stop();
//                tts.shutdown();
//            }
//
//            super.onPause();
//        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random r = new Random();

        String random = alphabet_meaning_voices;
        tts.setSpeechRate((float) 0.5);

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int amStreamMusicMaxVol = am.getStreamMaxVolume(am.STREAM_MUSIC);
        am.setStreamVolume(am.STREAM_MUSIC, amStreamMusicMaxVol, 0);

        tts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: Thanks McGuile for you consideration but problem is resolved.

Comment: Please mark it as resolved then and post the solution. Also as a suggestion, you could clean up that code with [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: McGuile can you please tell me how to mark question resolved because i haven't used stack overflow much.

Comment: Hollow green check. Click it! Post your solution too

Comment: can you tell me the location

Answer (score 0):

I this i used android intent to pass a specific value of button to another activity. The issue was in the code for button , i was using wrong key for the value that i was passing in another activity.:

```
ImageButton ib_s = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_s);
        ib_s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startActivity( new Intent( alphabat_pics.this, alphabet_meaning.class ));
                alphabet_meaning.putExtra("ib", string_array[18]);
                startActivity(alphabet_meaning);
            }
        });
```